# Javascript auto submit form not work

Tags: javascript, php, forms, submit

i have problem with my code..
i want to make it auto submit after fill the text box with length 10 digit of number.

this is my javascript code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $("#idnya").on("input propertychange", function()
        {
            if($(this).val().length ==15){
            $("#max").submit()
        }
    });

    </script>

</script>
```

and this's my php code

```
<?php
include "koneksi.php";

echo"

<body>
    <form id=max name='cingcing' action='lanjut.php' method='POST'>
    <center>

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2> <center> id </center> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> id number </td> <td> <input type=password id='idnya' name='idnya2'> </td> 
        </tr>
    </center>
    </form>
</body>
";
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." I think you forgot the `ready` function. And to check the length you can bind `keyup` event as below.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#idnya").on("keyup",function(){
                if($(this).val().length == 10){
                    $("#max").submit();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Solved ty my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

this might help u

```
    <?php
    include "koneksi.php";
    echo "
    <html><head></head>
    <body>
        <form id=max name='cingcing' action='lanjut.php' method='POST'>
        <center>

            <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2> <center> id </center> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> id number </td> <td> <input type=password id='idnya' name='idnya2'> </td> 
            </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>";
    ?>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $("#idnya").on("input propertychange", function()
        {
            if ($(this).val().length == 15) {
                $("#max").submit()
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your script with this

```
$("#idnya").on("input propertychange", function()
    {
        if($(this).val().length ==10){
        $("#max").submit()
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gaL59ang/) demo is here make it on keyup or change

```
  $("#idnya").keyup(function()
    {
        if($(this).val().length ==15){
        $("#max").submit()
    }
  });
```

// OR USE CHANGE it will run when you focus being away

```
  $("#idnya").change(function()
    {
        if($(this).val().length ==15){
        $("#max").submit()
    }
  });
```